# dash_auth not working when app is deployed

Tags: python, basic-authentication, plotly-dash

I am trying to use dash_auth for basic authentication in my app. It works fine locally, but when I deploy it to google cloud it shows 500 server error.

A simplified code is as follows:

```
import dash
import dash_auth
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = {
    'username': '1234'
}
app.title= 'APP'
server = app.server
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS
)
app.layout = html.Div('Hello')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

How can I make it work in GCP?

Comment: Exactly what I am dealing with. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make dash_auth work on GCP, but I made it work with a [modal](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/modal/) with 'static' backdrop, this is how it looks: [image]

Works just like the basic authentication, at least for what I need. I can even add a logout button which dash_auth wouldn't let me.

Edit:

It is not an ideal solution, but was a work around this issue I found useful. The login callback would look similar to this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('modal', 'is_open'),
    [Input('login_btn','n_clicks')],
    [State('username', 'value'),
    State('password','value')])
def usernamecall(clicks, username, password):
    if clicks==0 or clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    if username=='XXXX' and password=='XXXX':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

`login_btn` would be the button you see on the image with the label 'Ingresar' and username and password are `dcc.Input` components from [dash.plotly](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/input)

Comment: Can you please explain a little more how you did this? Some code example or link to examples?

Comment: Just added some more details